# setOnChildClickListener not being fired for ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-radiobutton

Hi All I have a expandable list view in my application where I generate radio button in the childview dynamically in the adapter. I have a requirement to the `setOnChildClickListener` in the expandable list view. But unfortunately, it is not being fired because of the radio buttons. I have tried `setFocusable/setclickable` to be set to false in the dynamically generated radio button. when I do that the `setOnChildClickListener` is fired. But I cant select individual radio buttons. So none helped. Can any one please help me with this? Please refer to my adapter class method,

This is my adapter method

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_child_radio_layout, null);


    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);
    radioGroup.setFocusable(false);
    final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[listDataChild.get(this.listOptionsHeader.get(groupPosition)).size()];
    radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
    for (int i = 0; i < listDataChild.get(this.listOptionsHeader.get(groupPosition)).size(); i++) {
        rb[i] = new RadioButton(context);
        rb[0].setChecked(true);
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, i);
        rb[i].setText(childText);
        rb[i].setId(i + 100);
        rb[i].setTag("radio-child " + childText);
        fontUtils.changeFontOfRadioButtontoOpenSansRegular(rb[i]);
        rb[i].setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.letter_small));
        radioGroup.addView(rb[i]);
        rb[i].setFocusable(false);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

This is my child layout `XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the onClick method I have used in my main activity class.

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            System.out.println("I am called");
            expandableListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: i think you forgot to apply listener for childview `mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);`

Comment: If it's not fired post you code with the listener maybe you do it incorrectly amd the problem is not with buttons , and also the docs restrict from using height wrap_content for ExListView and it's parent layout at the same time, you should specify the height in xml layout

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati I have actually used the listener in my main activity class.

Comment: @Rainmaker Please see my onclick method in the updated question. I dont get the print statement in the logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put return statement to your listener as true, not false and make sure you set it after you set your adapter!

EDIT:

As you cant select the rbuttons but your OnClick is fired let's add selection manually to the clicked button

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);
radioGroup.setFocusable(false);
final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[listDataChild.get(this.listOptionsHeader.get(groupPosition)).size()];
radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
for (int i = 0; i < listDataChild.get(this.listOptionsHeader.get(groupPosition)).size(); i++) {
    rb[i] = new RadioButton(context);
   // rb[0].setChecked(true);
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, i);
    rb[i].setText(childText);
    rb[i].setId(i + 100);
    rb[i].setTag("radio-child " + childText);
    fontUtils.changeFontOfRadioButtontoOpenSansRegular(rb[i]);
    rb[i].setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.letter_small));
    radioGroup.addView(rb[i]);
    rb[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            radioGroup.check(rb[i].getId());
      //if you allow multiple checked btns then leave it like that or if you don't then you need to check if there are other buttons checked in radioGroup and then unckeck them also in this method   
      });
    rb[i].setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: I changed it to true. But still I don't get the print statement.

Comment: I noticed you have your views set to focusable = false and clickable = false; change it to true as you are not able to catch clicks

Comment: when I set those values to false the `setOnChildClickListener` is fired but I cant select individual radio buttons. If I change it to true I can select individual radio buttons but `setOnChildClickListener` is not fired.

Comment: try  adding selection manually as you can;t get the rbutton selected but you get your onClick fired. You can also leave only one onCLick method only for rbuttons and do all the logic there depending when you want to catch your click events

Comment: That triggers the click. neat solution.